# Client-server implementation : which delta time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, game-loop, anti-cheat

Take a server with a **60 update per second** loop, that can receive client inputs at any time, store them in an array and process all of them at the next update tick. Once processed, the array is emptied. The server can lag and have less than 60 updates per second.
To prevent cheating, processing an input does : player.x += speed * deltaTime

The problem is to find the **correct deltaTime**.

If it is the deltaTime between each server tick, the player would move faster when the server lag, or the player can cheat (move faster) if he send more inputs than other players.

If the client sends the timestamp of the input, we could take the deltaTime between the consecutives same inputs (but the first input would have a deltaTime equals to 0). But once again, the player can cheat by sending an other timestamp...

A solution ?

Thank you very much !

Edit: also, there is a client-side prediction using a deltaTime between ticks.

Comment: I don't think your server should be operating on a deltaTime. Your clients should accomodate for network latency issues via interpolation and your server should deal with updates as they come in - cheating prevention should be handled in a different method IMO.

Comment: That's a solution but what if I have prediction client-side and an authoritative server ? The simulation has a deltaTime between each frame. For example, client send input to the server, store it (with the deltaTime) in an array and calculate the predicted state, server process it and send the authoritative state to the client 100ms later with the last processed input #. Client receives it, applies this old state and re-applies all the next input from this state. Problem is that the server and the client have both different deltaTime...

Comment: You can't expect two seperate devices (or even instances of your NodeJS app) to have similiar timings. deltaTime refers to the time between each frame, which is used for rendering - your server should not have a frame rate because it should not be displaying any frames.